# How to control image size that is in a ASP file?

Tags: html, css

I have this form that works fine, however, in my Logo.aspx file, I have 3 logos on the head of the form.

However, the Logos in the asp file pushes the third image to the right.

Is their a way to control the size of the logos in the front end?

This issue only occurs in IE10. But all other version of IE and Chrome, it works fine

Below is what I have tried and it does not work:

```
 <table style="width: 100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="left" width="10%"><!-- #INCLUDE FILE="scripts\Logo2_C.aspx" --></td>
<td align="right" width="90%"><img src="/images/logos/logo.png" /></td></tr></tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'inline-block' instead of a table:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;width:10%;"><!-- #INCLUDE FILE="scripts\Logo2_C.aspx" --></div>
<div style="display:inline-block;width:90%;"><img src="/images/logos/logo.png" /></div>
```

Comment: @ Jeanclaude: I have tried that and it just forces the 3 logo to the right and only see 25% of the image. This issue only occurs in IE10 and I do not know why

Comment: then your problem is maybe caused by the asp file @RobertoFlores

Comment: @ Jeanclaude: How would I determine if it is the asp file?